# Estela de SVG en transition de hover

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema y es que los iconos svg dejan una estela, cuando paso mi puntero encima de los iconos estos hacen un efecto de zoom y al quitarlos quiero que estos se devuelvan a su tamaño original de forma lenta, el problema es que dejan una estela de unos segundos, y no se como solucionarlo.

```
nav.redes-sociales svg {
  transition: all 1s;
}

nav.redes-sociales svg:hover {
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

[image: Si se dan cuenta debajo del logo quedan rayas blancas]

Si se dan cuenta debajo del logo quedan rayas blancas

Comment: quita el `transition` del hover

Comment: Si ya lo quite, pero sigue dejando una estela

Comment: Sería bueno que pongas una muestra replicable de tu código

Comment: Creo que aquí se entiende mejor. https://codepen.io/salt0s/pen/RwKKjby
Si te das cuenta en el incono de Facebook, Pinterest y Instagram dejan rastro y a veces no desaparecen

Comment: Gracias por proporcionar el código de ejemplo, ya publiqué una respuesta donde se muestra una manera de solucionar ese error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La verdad me tomó algo de tiempo encontrar una solución a este problema, al parecer no es un problema de código, si no un problema de renderizado por parte del propio navegador. Busqué un largo rato alguna propiedad de CSS que pueda corregir el problema, pero al parecer no existe. Por lo cuál la única solución que se me ocurrió fue forzar el pintado de los pixeles donde se muestra la Estela de la animación.
Agregue el siguiente código dentro del siguiente selector: `nav.redes-sociales svg { box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05); }` el código final debería quedar algo así:

```css
body {
  background-color: #4e3535;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

nav.redes-sociales {
  text-align: center;
}

nav.redes-sociales a {
  width: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

nav.redes-sociales a:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

nav.redes-sociales svg {
  transition: all 1s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05); /*Este es el código agregado*/
}

nav.redes-sociales svg:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e0f3daff58.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Oswald&family=PT+Sans&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png" />
    <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

    <meta name="theme-color" content="#fafafa" />
 <header class="site-header">
      <div class="hero">
        <div class="contenido-header">
          <nav class="redes-sociales">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-pinterest-p"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
          </nav>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo :) si sirvió, ya pude solucionar eso, muchas gracias :))